# Force X11 to keep xmodmap changes

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts

On my Lenovo T420 I use this:

```
        # Lenovo back/forward => PgUp/PgDown                                         
        xmodmap -e 'keycode 166=Prior' 2>/dev/null                                   
        xmodmap -e 'keycode 167=Next' 2>/dev/null
```

to remap the Back and Forward keys (just above the Left and Right keys) from:

```
keycode 166 = XF86Back NoSymbol XF86Back
keycode 167 = XF86Forward NoSymbol XF86Forward
```

to PgUp and PgDn:

```
keycode 166 = Prior NoSymbol Prior
keycode 167 = Next NoSymbol Next
```

Unfortunately this configuration is reverted now and then (it happens at unpredictable times). I can also force the reverting back by briefly changing to a console outside X11 (e.g. by pressing CTRL-ALT-F2).

Is there a way I can force X11 to keep my remapping?

Answer (score 0):

Putting this into ~/.Xmodmap

```
keycode 167 = Next NoSymbol Next
keycode 166 = Prior NoSymbol Prior
```

fixed it for changing to console. It remains to be seen if it also fixed it for the unpredictable times.